# Does SQL Server Broker require TRUSTWORTHY?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

SQL Server >=2016

Do I need to set trustworthy on for database to run broker? Does it require this setting? Or it is possible somehow run Broker and do not set TRUSTWORTHY ON?

Comment: DB does not require TRUSTWORTHY. However, I sometimes see TRUSTWORTHY used to work-around for the sandboxed EXECUTE AS context for activated procs that need cross-database access. There are other/better ways to do that (e.g. certificates).

Comment: I think trustworthy is often used in example SB code where the queues are in different databases. As @DanGuzman says though... certificates can get around that issue as well.

Comment: Thank you. I have a situation: a db backed up on one server then restored on other and its SB is disabled but it works in the source db . I see that the 2nd db has Trustworthy Off. Thought may that is the problem.